# Send email with WatchKit

Tags: cocoa, watchkit, watchos-2

Looking for a way to have an WatchKit extension send an email.

Obviously I can get it to open a MFMailComposeViewController on the iPhone, but it defeats the purpose of using the watch if the user has to get the phone out to press "Send".

Is there any way of going this?

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible currently if you implement your own email client. If you want the user to be able to use the email accounts on their Mail app, the best you could do is adopt handoff and make it **easier** for your user to just swipe up into a MFMailComposeViewController instance in your iPhone app from the lockscreen.

[image]